# how to docker run, support Ctrl+C, and not combine stderr

Tags: docker, tty, docker-run

I have a bunch of scripts that I run inside docker containers. They're called by scripts and are not meant to be interactive. The outer scripts are sometimes run in a terminal, and sometimes not (as in CI).

I want to support users killing the scripts using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, so I currently pass `-t` (`--tty`). But I discovered that this option combines `stdout` and `stderr`. I don't want that.

Is there a way I can support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and still have `stderr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found is [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini). Specifically, add the following to the `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.18.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "-g", "--"]
```

This is taken mostly verbatim from the tini README, and adds the `-g`, which makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> work more like you would expect.

Now there's no need to use `--tty`, and no smushing of `stdout` and `stderr`.

## How does it work?

`tini`'s author does a great job [explaining it](https://github.com/krallin/tini/issues/8). But to summarize, docker runs your process as PID 1. PID 1 is normally init, and it has some responsibilities, like handling signals. `bash`, and most other programs you might run in your container, don't do those things. `tini` does, and it does such a good job, they added it to `docker` as `--init`. The only problem with that flag is that it doesn't add `-g`, which is important for shell scripts. So I recommend adding it to the `Dockerfile` manually.